# Display custom footer for twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap, customization, typeahead.js

I am trying to create something like the search functionality on twitter using bootstrap and the typeahead plugin.

So far i have managed to display results differently based on type (people / etc) by compiling a list of results from the ajax call and referencing that in the 'highlighter' function.

What i want to do is display a custom footer for the dropdown that pops up with the results like on twitter  ('view all results', 'search all people for test' etc.).

[image: Twitter search]

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.typeahed').typeahed(null, {
    name: 'suggestions',
    templates: {
        footer: Handlebars.compile('Results for {{ query }}'),
    }
});
```

Comment: This answers is not accepted but I can confirm it works!